# Add div programmatically to a refreshing table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on my own ColumnResizer for a table. I know that there are some PlugIns that are doing exactly this, but I would love to write my own one.

To create a resizable column I am appending a div to each th-Element of the table programmatically like this:

```
jQuery.each($("#table > table > thead > tr > th"), function() { 
    if(this.id !== ""){
        var div = createDiv($(this).outerHeight());
        $(this).append($(div));
        $(this).css('position','relative');
        this.width = $(this).outerWidth()
        console.log(div)
    }
 });
```

The function "createDiv()" looks like this:

```
function createDiv(tableHeight){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).css('top','0');
    $(div).css('right','0');
    $(div).css('width','2px');
    $(div).css('position','absolute');
    $(div).css('cursor','col-resize');
    $(div).css('userSelect','none');
    $(div).css('height',tableHeight + 'px');
    return div;
}
```

This is working fine then entering the page.

The problem is that the table can be multi-paged. So you can switch between pages of the same table. Each page switch is refreshing the table and here is the problem: After such a refresh I cant append the div to the th-elements .... Its just not working. I am calling exactly the same methods when the table is being refreshed. I also added a timeOut because I thought that the table isnt finished loading yet but it also didnt help.

I already tried to add

```
$(document).ready()
```

but it also didnt work.

One funny thing is that then I am adding an

```
alert("test")
```

to the refreshTable() function, the divs are there after closing the alert.

Does any one know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How table refreshed?

Comment: Im using Ensemble from InterSystems - It is a method called refreshContents()